# Question about differentiability in $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, inner-products, symmetric-matrices, differential

I found this peculiar problem:

> Let $A\in \mathcal{M}_n(\mathbb{R})$ be a symmetric matrix, $B\in \mathcal{M}_{1\times n}(\mathbb{R})$ and let $C$ be a real constant. Prove that $p:\mathbb{R}^n\to \mathbb{R}$ defined as:$$p(\mathbf{x})=\langle A\mathbf{x},\mathbf{x}\rangle +B\mathbf{x}+ C$$is differentiable in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Clearly $B\mathbf{x} +C$ is differentiable but the inner product involving $A$ is causing me some trouble. I don't get why the condition of $A$ being symmetrical is set, and I could extend the inner product in terms of $A$ to prove differentiabilty by justifying it's a $C^1 (\mathbb{R}^n)$ function; but it seems out of place. I wonder if there's an inequality (Cauchy-Schwarz will help?) I could use to prove that the inner product is differentiable by definition, or some other quicker/fancier way.

Comment: Not really sure what your question is. You seem to be saying that you could solve this problem in one of a few different ways?

Comment: There are several fine answers, and I agree with them. In case you feel obliged to write more, you might assert that the function is $C^1$ on any smooth, parametric path through any point $\tilde{x}\in \mathbb{R}^n$. It goes without saying, of course, unless $-$ for your audience $-$ it doesn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right, the condition of $A$ being symmetrical is useless here.

The inner product is [bilinear and continuous](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bilinear_map#Continuity_and_separate_continuity) (as is any bilinear map in finite dimension, but here you can indeed use Cauchy-Schwarz inequality to prove it).

Any continuous bilinear map $B$ is smooth and
$$DB(a,b)(h,k)=B(a,k)+B(h,b).$$

Comment: Thank you so muchh!! It will be better to propose my students to work on proving the differentiability of a general bilinear function then :))

Answer (score 2):

It is true for each matrix $A= (a_{ij})$. The $i$-th component of $A \mathbf x$ is $\sum_{j=1}^n a_{ij}x_j$ and therefore we get.
$$\langle A \mathbf x, \mathbf x \rangle = \sum_{i=1}^n(\sum_{j=1}^n a_{ij}x_j ) x_i = \sum_{i,j=1}^n a_{ij}x_jx_i .$$
Clearly all partial derivatives exist and are continuous, and therefore $\langle A \mathbf x, \mathbf x \rangle$ is differentiable.

Answer (score 2):

$p(\mathbf{x})$ is a polynomial function of the coordinates of $\mathbf{x}$. Polynomials are differentiable. I think that is all you need to say. I agree that the condition that $\mathbf{A}$ is symmetrical is irrelevant.